# Python os.chdir changes "\" to "\\" when passing path/directory path, any ideas to fix?

Tags: python, python-3.x, operating-system, chdir

I am trying to change directory using a variable which contains a path but os.chdir changes the \ in the path to \ which makes it undreadable/undefined for the os module and crashes.

any ideas on how to overcome this please?[shot [][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TqyEb.png)

Comment: It is bad to post code or data as pictures.  There is no way to copy and paste a picture into a code editor. So it will be much harder, and thus less likely, for someone to help. To get the most out of the site it is important to [ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), that includes creating a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `raw strings` when dealing with file paths.

```
BOOKING_DIR = r"path to your dir"
```

Comment: My path is stored in a variable and I can't use r with the name of the variable where the string is stored.

Comment: In that case maybe try changing damn `backslashes` with `double backslashes`. Man, I couldn't write it with \`s haha. @MahmoudYassine

Comment: I did that but os.chdir made them 4 slashes !

Comment: Last thing that comes to my mind is, you can try to split the whole string by `\ ` and then join them with the `os.path.join()` @MahmoudYassine